# European Time capsule in Canada

Tags: wifi, time-capsule

Is it possible to use a (European/French)Time Capsule in Canada ?
If yes, is there any particular configuration to apply ?

Thank You.

Comment: did you try it? what was the problem (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from my experience you can do that. I lived in the UK and currently use mine in the US. No special configuration required, just configure it to your new router.